I need to take inputs of confidence levels and orders so far in a day and use it to predict how many more orders will come in, using past data
Using replaceable sets of data about past orders and the times in which they were placed, and inputs for the confidence level and the amount of orders already placed, estimate the amount of orders that will arrive within a certain time period as a percentage of the orders already placed
I figured I need to make a csv file I think and access it in python, and then I need to take the times of the orders and calculate the hourly rate or daily rate, maybe finding a mean hourly rate, but then I need to apply a confidence level and then somehow apply it to the data to output the amount of orders remaining for the day????
I also have no clue which modules to import to solve this, i need to also learn how to implement the confidence level and the analysis of the data that i have given.
I have no idea how to create a csv file, and when i tried to use excel it just wouldn't save.
I also tried to import some modules such as 'pandas' but it didnt work.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
